# Are password and username revealed when server ip and domain ip are equal?

Tags: encryption

Using plesk, I run some cron jobs with domains on my own server, ie for instance

```
https://username:password@domain.com/cron.php
```

The ip of my server is the same ip of domain.com.

Will others see username and password?

If yes, how do I run the cron.php which requires username and password from within the server?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain resolves (on that host) to one of the IPs attached to an interface on that host, then the traffic will remain within the host.  However, should you add a CDN (Cloudflare, etc.) at some point in the future, then your traffic will go out over the internet to the CDN before coming back to your backend.

If you're using a proper implementation of HTTPS (as implied by the URL in your example), then the username and password are not revealed even *if* the traffic traveled over the network.  (Unless using an SSL-terminating CDN, but you'd already be putting a lot of trust in that CDN.)

Comment: Yup, the TLS layer is created first (encrypted tunnel) before the HTTP GET. Hence data is encrypted as long as HTTP s is done :)